# JavaFX tableview column switches values

Tags: mysql, javafx, tableview

it's me again. so i have this javafx tableview which i have loaded dynamically with rows and columns from my database. it works out well but there's something i realized. two particular columns in the tableview switch their values. it happened once and when i cancelled the process and ran the program again, it didn't happen, then out of the blues, it happened again. i attached an image so you'd understand better. THANKS GUYS!!

below is the code that populates the tableview with Columns and rows from the database. i don't get any error when i run this.

```
 public void buildData () {

    String str = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE";

    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        ResultSet rs = DBaseUtils.dbaseExecuteQuery(str);

        for(int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            String columnName = rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1);
            TableColumn<Employee, String> column = new TableColumn<>(columnName);
            column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(columnName));
            column.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Employee>forTableColumn());
            column.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Employee, String> event) {
                    TableColumn<Employee, String> col = event.getTableColumn();
                    int row = event.getTablePosition().getRow();
                    ObservableValue<String> observe = col.getCellObservableValue(row);
                    if (observe instanceof WritableValue) {
                        ((WritableValue<String>) observe).setValue(event.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
            });
            empTable.getColumns().addAll(column);
        }


        while(rs.next()) {
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.setEmployeeId(rs.getString(1));
            emp.setFirstname(rs.getString(2));
            emp.setLastname(rs.getString(3));
            emp.setSex(rs.getString(4));
            emp.setEmail(rs.getString(5));
            emp.setPhoneNumber(rs.getString(6));
            emp.setAddress(rs.getString(7));
            emp.setHireDate(rs.getString(8));
            emp.setState(rs.getString(9));
            emp.setSalary(rs.getString(10));
            emp.setDepartment(rs.getString(11));
            emp.setSsn(rs.getString(12));

            data.add(emp);
        }
        empTable.setItems(data);
        empTable.setEditable(true);



    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error building data! ");
    }
}
```

i also attached the model class, well... just in case. 
notice the naming conventions for the Property methods, i had to use that because those were the exact names on my database. and since it PropertyValueFactory uses Reflection.

```
public  class Employee {
private SimpleStringProperty employeeId;
private SimpleStringProperty firstname;
private SimpleStringProperty lastname;
private SimpleStringProperty sex;
private SimpleStringProperty email;
private SimpleStringProperty phoneNumber;
private SimpleStringProperty hireDate;
private SimpleStringProperty address;
private SimpleStringProperty state;
private StringProperty salary;
private SimpleStringProperty department;
private SimpleStringProperty ssn;
private long time;

public Employee() {
    this.employeeId = new SimpleStringProperty();
    this.firstname = new SimpleStringProperty();
    this.lastname = new SimpleStringProperty();
    this.sex = new SimpleStringProperty();
    this.email = new SimpleStringProperty();
    this.phoneNumber = new SimpleStringProperty();
    this.hireDate = new SimpleStringProperty();
    this.address = new SimpleStringProperty();
    this.state = new SimpleStringProperty();
    this.salary = new SimpleStringProperty();
    this.department = new SimpleStringProperty();
    this.ssn = new SimpleStringProperty();
}

public String getEmployeeId() {
    return employeeId.get();
}

public void setEmployeeId(String id) {
    this.employeeId.set(id);
}

public StringProperty EMPLOYEE_IDProperty() {
    return employeeId;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstname.get();
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname.set(firstname);
}

public StringProperty FIRST_NAMEProperty() {
    return firstname;
}

public String getLastName() { return lastname.get(); }

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname.set(lastname);
}

public StringProperty LAST_NAMEProperty() {
    return lastname;
}

public String getSex() {
    return sex.get();
}

public void setSex(String sex) {
    this.sex.set(sex);
}

public StringProperty SEXProperty() {
    return sex;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email.get();
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email.set(email);
}

public StringProperty EMAILProperty() {
    return email;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber.get();
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber.set(phoneNumber);
}

public StringProperty PHONE_NUMBERProperty() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public String getHireDate() {
    return hireDate.get();
}

public void setHireDate(String date) {
    this.hireDate.set(date);
}

public SimpleStringProperty HIRE_DATEProperty() {
    return hireDate;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address.get();
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address.set(address);
}

public StringProperty ADDRESSProperty() {
    return address;
}

public String getState() {
    return state.get();
}
```

Here's the image. notice the different values in the HIRE_DATE COLUMN AND ADDRESS COLUMN
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you sure your SQL queries are always returning the expected results?

Comment: Yes they are @Zephyr I used a println method to read the columns after loading them and it comes out the same way I have them in the database

Comment: What is the actual thing that got swapped? The headers, or the data? If it's the headers, then your columns may not be returned in a fixed order.

Comment: Not the headers, it's the data. Please look at the image I attached. Thanks. @Jai

Comment: The picture doesn't tell us whether the 2 column headers swapped positions, or whether all the data swapped columns. Anyway, I don't think anyone can figure out exactly what went wrong with a proper [mcve].

Comment: The headers did not swap positions. It's the data, looking at it youd see there are two columns meant to hold dates & addresses. Looking at the values, you'd see that they have them mixed up. Each column having both dates & addresses

Comment: sorry, but your code is a complete mess: please strip it down to not confuse us ;) a) don't map everything to String, instead use correct data type b) use _fx_ naming conventions when it comes to properties, everything else will lead into desaster c) if you really want to automatically create the valueFactories from the database field name (personally, I don't see any advantage, you'll hand-code the getter/setter/property of the data item anyway), implement some formatter that converts the db-name into a valid fx property name..

Comment: Thanks, this is a rookie project. I'm just trying to gather as much knowledge as I can get from this. Thanks for the reply. @Kleopatra

Comment: With regards to your last suggestion, could you point me in a direction as to how I'd be able to implement a formatter that converts db-name into valid fx property name. Graçias. @Kleopatra

Comment: just do it, simple string manipulation ;) but in your shoes, I would start much much smaller: one data class with properties following fx naming conventions, hard-coded data, one tableView showing that data .. (there are tutorials out there, meant to be read <g>) When that's working, add complexity